# How to determine the number of cores on a machine using PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a built-in function in PHP that will return the number of cores on a machine?  I’m running on Mac OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks).

Comment: php function no, you will have to call an os function, i could tell you how on *nix, but but macs are a mystery

Comment: Try with [this one](https://gist.github.com/rlemon/1780212) and tell if that work

Comment: @76200 does Mac OS X 10.9.3  have a /proc/stat file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a php built in function, but you can execute a command to get the result. On OSX 10.9.3 the following will return the number of cores.

```
$output = '';
$command = "sysctl hw.ncpu | awk '{print $2}'";
exec($command,$output);
echo $output[0];
```